# f.write loop runs with no errors, doesn't write to file

Tags: python

Our reporting service broke here at work and being the office's only millenial, I've been tasked with pulling email addresses out of a what is essentially a jumble of random addresses and customer information. I've written the following in Python and so far it's done really well with finding emails amid the chaos and appending them into an array:

```
f = open("c:/text.txt");                #open file
c = open("C:/users/user/documents/test255.txt",'w+');
total_emails=0;
tally = [];
line_count = 0;                                    #set line count 
for line in f:                          #loop through lines
    character_count = 0                 #set character count
    for character in line:              #loop through characters
        if character == "@":          #Locate email symbol
            beginning = 0;
            ending = 0;
            middle = character_count;
            print "Found an Email!";
            while(line[character_count]!=" "):
                character_count-=1;
            beginning = character_count+1;
            character_count=middle;
            while(line[character_count]!=" "):
                character_count+=1;
            ending = character_count;
            email = line[beginning:ending];
            tally.append(email);
            total_emails+=1;
        character_count+=1;
    line_count+=1;
c.close;
f.close;
```

So far, this seems to be the most preferred solution without importing apocryphal libraries:

```
c.write ('\n'.join('\t'.join(x) for x in tally))
```

I know I could probably just cut these straight out of the shell and paste them into excel, but I'd rather learn to do this right by having the different emails export into a .txt file with a line break after each record. I've read a lot of examples and a lot of them seem to initialize in Python with no errors but when I open the file nothing is there! I've written this so that python makes a new file in the chosen directory, so I'm fairly certain it isn't a permissions issue but I'm willing to take whatever advice I can get now.

Comment: You should really consider splitting your program up into separate functions, so you can separately develop and test each one. Also, use the context manager `with` to handle files: `with open(...) as f:`.

Comment: Semicolons at the ends of lines are unnecessary in Python and highly discouraged.

Comment: And where is your `write` in your loop ?

Comment: You appear to be reinventing the [CSV wheel](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html); you may want to use the batteries Python provides you with instead.

Comment: You are also *not closing the files*; `c.close` only references the method. `c.close()` and `f.close()` would also flush the buffers; you may well have written data but cannot see the data if your Python program remains open and `f` and `c` are never  closed.

Comment: I like the idea of using different functions to get this done. Maybe OO will make this easier to tackle. I'll start killing the semicolons, bad habits from doing JS and Java I guess.

Comment: No need for OOP here, just a few separate functions (import data, process data, export data). Also, look into regular expressions for finding your email addresses.

Comment: @AaronHart, where exactly in the code is your c.write? Before or after the c.close?

Comment: c.write is the 3rd to final line, just before the f.close and c.close calls.

Comment: @jon - isn't that still technically OOP? I always assumed whenever you were making your own functions you were doing OOP. I'm guessing I have this wrong though.

Comment: No, OOP generally refers to developing your own object classes.

Comment: Excuse my crude example, but something like: dog bill = new dog{} is OOP rather than simply making functions, right?

Comment: @AaronHart, is there a reason you don't want to use re library?

Comment: Mostly ignorance, with a little pride and a stubborn desire to learn the more tedious approach before moving on to shortcuts @user3885927 - I'm thinking I'm going to cave on this one, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the inner join function doesn't have the comprehension as the argument:

```
c.write ('\n'.join('\t'.join(x) for x in tally))
```

should be

```
c.write ('\n'.join('\t'.join(x for x in tally)))
```

or just

```
c.write('\n'.join('\t'.join(tally)))
```

The `join` function takes an iterable as the argument, so you have to give it the whole comprehension as the argument

Comment: OK, but ... won't this error "write the wrong thing" instead of just "write nothing" ?

Comment: And, of course, `'\t'.join(x for x in tally)` can (and should?) be shortened to `'\t'.join(tally)`.

Comment: This should write all the bits of tally separated by tabs, which probably isn't what OP intended, yes

Comment: @jwodder, good catch, I'd update to add that, but working on mobile is a pain, feel free to add it :)

Comment: I'd be happy just to get anything. I'm hitting a new problem with this self-same code now if your keen to take a look:
  File "C:\Users\ahart\Documents\new.py", line 18, in <module>
    while(line[character_count]!=" "):
IndexError: string index out of range. *******************************************

I got the above attempting to run the code on the actual file rather than the much smaller file I used for testing.

Comment: use re module to find your emails instead of moving your index around on the lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you use re module (Regular Expressions) your parsing would be much simpler. Something like this:

```
import re
#do your file open stuff
for line in f:
    #line="hello me@you.com he@there@.com some more stuff here"
    temp = re.findall('[^\s]*@[^\s]*', line)
    #temp=['me@you.com', 'he@there.com']
    #write addresses fetched so far to the file, one in each line
    c.write('\n'.join(temp))
#close your file
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Holy moly, that's elegant! Thanks!